# android camerx finalizeEvent getError() returns 8

Tags: android-camerax

Please consult Android Studio (Java) CamerX1.2.0 to write the source code for implementing the recording function. The exception finalizeEvent. getError() returns 8

```
// 开始录制并注册事件监听器
            recording = pendingRecording.start(
                    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), // 指定回调在主线程执行
                    videoRecordEvent ->  {
                // 这里处理各种类型的 videoRecordEvent，例如 VideoRecordEvent.Start, VideoRecordEvent.Finalize 等
                if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Start) {
                    // 处理开始录制事件
                    runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "2开始录制中...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) {
                    // 处理录制结束事件
                    VideoRecordEvent.Finalize finalizeEvent = (VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent;
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        int a=finalizeEvent.getError();
                        if (!finalizeEvent.hasError()) {
                            // 录制成功完成
                            String message = "录制成功完成，视频已保存至: " + videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {

                            // 处理错误
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "录制出错", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

尝试了不同手机还是
finalizeEvent.getError();
finalizeEvent: VideoRecordEvent$Finalize@14966
8
返回8，希望得到帮助，谢谢！